# Excel automation of row/table

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically what I am trying to achieve can be found in the picture *Task Description* below. I have inserted comments to summarize

I have also uploaded the sample of the excel sheet [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aojtb-lU1PMexW-OtnrFdYkFtjrS).

If you need to know more details please let me know.

Task Description:

[image: Task Description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the command you are looking for is called COUNTIFS:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Answer (score 0):

I used SUMIFS  see screenshot... 
...edit:  also, in the "Type" column in table, it requires you to enter "Digital" or "Paper"  you're original "Y"/"N" doesn't work with forumulas I used

[image]

Comment: Hello DHH,

Thank you for your reply, but I am confused on what you need to put in this table that you've mentioned? Are you able to make these changes on the sample I shared on OneDrive? So I can learn from what you did?

Comment: I uploaded it... see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n82OxBgyFO4QMUqMhCKlNXDQ74Abdo_W/view?usp=sharing